# Restrict Search Query To After Specific Date

Tags: pre-get-posts

This code is not working

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_filter' );
function search_filter($query) {

if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {

$query->set( array( 'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ) ) ) );
    }

    }
}
```

I want to remove all results prior to jan 1 2013 so only posts after the 1/1/2013 will be shown in the results.

Comment: Not an answer but [square bracket shorthand is supported for arrays in php 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772534/php-difference-between-array-and) and later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this problematic line:

```
$query->set( array( 'date_query' => array(
```

it should be

```
$query->set( 'date_query', array(
```

So try instead this form:

```
$query->set( 'date_query', 
    [
        [
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ]
    ] 
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Why use square brackets instead of round brackets?

Comment: You're welcome. The `[]` is a shorthand notation for `array()` in PHP 5.4+. @Dev